# Jquery add style on ASP TextBoxes Not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net

```
function valid() {
    var ids1 = $('input[id*="<%= txtCompnayCode.ClientID %>"]');
    var ids2 = $('input[id*="<%= txtCompanyCodeOld.ClientID %>"]');

    if (ids1.value === ids2.value) {
         $(ids2).addClass('Match');
         //$('input[id*="<%= txtCompnayCode.ClientID %>"]').addClass('Match');
        //$('#<%= txtCompnayCode.ClientID %>').css('background-color', 'red');
        $(ids2).attr('style', 'background-color: red !important');
   }
   else {
        alert('unmatch');
   }
}
```

all working fine....like it comparing fields and give alert.. but not adding up css style for a unlatch field, below four lines I'hv tried but not working, kindly suggest any solution that works on ASP.NET

```
 $(ids2).addClass('Match');
 //$('input[id*="<%= txtCompnayCode.ClientID %>"]').addClass('Match');
 //$('#<%= txtCompnayCode.ClientID %>').css('background-color', 'red');
 $(ids2).attr('style', 'background-color: red !important');
```

Comment: i think the last four lines are messed up.

Comment: yeah stackoverflow messed it up, fixed not

Answer (score 0):

use `$(ids2).css({'background-color' : 'red !important'});`